# Create difference matrix from data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm quite long time struggling with the following issue. I need to create something like difference matrix from data frame - see below.

```
price <- data.frame(prod=c("prod1","prod2","prod3","prod4","prod5"),
                price=c(10,14,16,20,32))
```

Data frame looks like this one, but in real is quite huge data set.

```
prod price
prod1    10
prod2    14
prod3    16
prod4    20
prod5    32
```

From this data frame I need to create matrix with price differencies, where each of the combinations in following matrix represents differencies in absolute value between product prices - see below.

```
 # Price difference matrix (differencies between prices must be in absolute value) - desired output:

           prod1    prod2   prod3   prod4
prod2        4  
prod3        6        2
prod4       10        6       4
prod5       22       18      16      12
```

Please, could anyone help me or give me some advice, how could I create desired matrix (see above) from my origin data frame. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dist` for that purpose

```
dist(price$price)
#    1  2  3  4
# 2  4         
# 3  6  2      
# 4 10  6  4   
# 5 22 18 16 12
```